# How do I boot to USB with Win10 media creation tool from GRUB 2.04?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, usb

I was trying to uninstall Linux from my dual boot system and ran into a problem. I deleted the Ubuntu partition and closed my laptop while I went and downloaded a win 10 creation tool to revert the boot loader. Unfortunately that turned off my PC so when i came back I am stuck in GRUB and don't know how to boot from USB. I tried "ls -lh" and noticed the only thing that is different when the usb is plugged in is there is a hd0 that says the file system cannot be accessed. I am assuming that is the usb with win 10 creation tool because it isn't there when the USB isn't plugged in. I set it as the root but when I tried chainloader +1 like has been suggested for this scenario is get invalid buffer alignment. Can anybody help me boot from USB?

Comment: Is the USB set as first HDD in BIOS?

Comment: Have you got another computer that works, or can you borrow a computer? It is probably easiest to use a computer with a woriking operating system in order to download some iso file(s) and create a USB boot drive(s), that can install or repair the operating system(s), that you want in the problematic computer.

Comment: Try preesing f12 before you get grub and booting from there. Do u have uefi or bios?

Comment: @sudodus I have a USB with the win 10 install on it that can repair. The issues is getting the boot drive to work in GRUB because it won't let me access it.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha GRUB boots instantly and won't let me access bios

Comment: Do you have fast boot in your BIOS enabled? You should be able to boot into firmware settings before grub

Comment: These links and links from them may help you boot into the Windows 10 installer drive: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/bootUSB; https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot/